# How is this possible: OnPaint processed while in WaitOne

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have a `ManualResetEvent`. At one point, I wait on that event using `WaitOne`. To my amazement, I received an `OnPaint` event while in the `WaitOne`. This happens quite often too.

The stack trace looks like this:

[image]

I understood that a `WaitOne` would block the current thread and would not allow any other code to be executed until the event fires.

Could someone explain what happens here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is by design.  The CLR honors the contract of a single-threaded apartment (STA).  The main thread of a GUI app is STA as is required in Windows programming, the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() method ensures that.

Hard rules for an STA thread are that it must pump a message loop (like Application.Run) and can never block.  Blocking an STA thread is highly likely to cause deadlock when background threads use any COM apartment threaded objects.  There are many of them, the clipboard and WebBrowser are common ones you'll encounter in a .NET program.  Many less visible ones as well, available as .NET wrapper classes.

The CLR ensures blocking can't cause deadlock by pumping a message loop when you use the lock statement or call the Wait method of the synchronization classes.  Or Thread.Join().  That message loop dispatches the WM_PAINT message, causing the Paint event to run.

You need to restructure your program to ensure this doesn't cause a problem.  Pretty important to focus on not blocking the main thread at all.  It is very rarely needed when you have, say, the BackgroundWorker class or Control.BeginInvoke() at your disposal.  For some kind of odd reason the Mutex class doesn't do this kind of pumping, that could be another way.  Although deadlock is lurking around the corner if you do.

Comment: Your answers are always an insight, learned something new again.

Comment: The reason I'm doing a wait is because I'm waiting on network traffic to complete. The server provides data I need to build up the UI. Specifically, I am lazy loading a list view. When a row comes into view which I do not have data of, I need to fetch that data to be able to react to the paint. This is by design. I'll see whether the `Mutex` class helps. If you have other suggestions, they sure are welcome.

Comment: Just do this the other way around.  The arrival of the data can induce the paint event.  Control.BeginInvoke and Invalidate().  This will be a lot easier in C# 5 with asych/await.  Use a state machine if necessary until then.

Comment: I've created a test case where I have two forms in two threads. `Form1` I make wait on a `ManualResetEvent` and `Form2` has a button that signals the event. What I'm seeing is that `WM_PAINT` events are coming through but I cannot otherwise interact with the blocked form. Also, a `BeginInvoke` does not come through. Do you have any idea how I can find out what messages will and what messages will not come through?

Comment: That's because the CLR is pumping, not the Winforms message loop.  It doesn't know anything about the Control.BeginInvoke plumbing.  Keyboard shortcuts and tabbing ought to go wrong too.  However, I'm not sure about your observation that input messages aren't being dispatched.  It does make sense, allowing the user to close the window would be disastrous.  I just never dared do this and am not sure what kind of pumping is done.  The sscli20 source doesn't have it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After some research, the problem doesn't look as drastic as I though. I'm going to add a `Loading` flag, suppress the offending `WM_PAINT` and force an `Invalidate` when the `WaitOne` completes. I think that should be enough.

Comment: +1: Great answer. But how do you know this? I checked `[StaThread]` on msdn: "... Using this attribute in an application that does not use COM interop has no effect."

Comment: @jdv - not using COM in a gui app is impossible.  When you type Ctrl+V you're using COM.  OpenFileDialog is another big one, lots of lots of it with the shell extension handlers.  That's not explicit COM interop, that's Windows doing it for you.  It still needs an STA thread.  It is so core to the way Windows works that the CLR had to support it.  COM taking care of threading works rather well, there are very few questions about it at SO.  The same cannot be said about .NET threading, many, many questions about it.  It is however *much* more flexible.  At a price.

Comment: @Hans, Yeah, I know, it's everywhere. I'm just find the docs outright misleading.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this behavior too for the `lock()` statement. Apparently the .net framework Thread classes starts a message loop when waiting for a lock on the UI thread. This just explains what is happening. The reasoning could be to prevent deadlocks when working with legacy STA COM objects.  I am not aware of a way to prevent this.