# Wait for a message in a NativeWindow

Tags: c#, messaging, wndproc, autoresetevent, nativewindow

What I am trying to do is catch and wait for a `WM_TIMER` message on a window within my process (though one which I have no control of).

I am trying to use an `AutoResetEvent` in order to wait for the message.

The `WaitForMaterialUpdate` method connects the `NativeWindow` to the window, and blocks until it receives a message.

This is the code I am using:

```
public class MaterialEditorWindow : NativeWindow
{
    private const int WM_TIMER = 0x0113;

    private AutoResetEvent waiter;

    public void WaitForMaterialUpdate(IntPtr handle)
    {
        waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        AssignHandle(handle);
        waiter.WaitOne(5000);
        ReleaseHandle();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
         if (m.Msg == WM_TIMER) waiter.Set();
         base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I am not in a very debuggable environment, but I have confirmed using `MessageBox` that the window is in fact receiving `WM_TIMER` messages during the wait period, yet `WaitOne` always waits the full 5000 ms timeout period before returning.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is that running in the UI thread?

Comment: @SLaks Yes. Should I be calling `WaitOne` from a different thread? If so, why do I still get the `MessageBox` popups even in this state?

Comment: `MessageBox` pumps UI messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WaitOne()` is a blocking call.
The UI thread will not receive any messages until `WaitOne()` returns.  Since you set the wait handle when the UI thread receives a message, you have a deadlock.

You need to do this on a background thread, or simply call a callback when you receive the message.

Comment: I see. Thanks. As I need this done synchronously due the specifics of the environment, I will probably go with `while (!msgReceived) Application.DoEvents()` to pump the messages myself instead of the `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: This is not accurate, the CLR pumps a message loop when WaitOne() is called on an UI thread.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540244/how-is-this-possible-onpaint-processed-while-in-waitone