# Is there a way to WAIT for a thread to complete processing while pumping windows messages?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading

I was trying to use AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() on a GUI thread hoping that it would not block the GUI thread completely and allow the GUI thread to keep pumping windows messages while it waits for a signal (similar to Thread.Wait()). I learned that wasn't a correct assumption.

So am looking for a way to be on the GUI Thread and wait for a thread to finish running (similar to using AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()) but keep the message pump flowing. (Please no DoEvents())

I guess the short question is: **Is there a WAIT in .NET that pumps windows messages (especially "Paint" event) while it is waiting?**

Comment: That's going to depend on the flavor of asynchrony that what you're using supports.  It might call a callback, it might fire an event, it might return a `Task`, or any number of other options.  You need to use whatever it exposes to allow you to execute some code when the asynchronous operation completes.

Comment: but which wait() can I use that will pump windows messages?

Comment: You need to use the method provided by the source of asynchronous you're using, as I said.  When the method is asynchronous, you aren't blocking the thread, and it's able to continue on pumping messages.

Comment: use async from latest .net

Comment: @Servy: I am not sure what you mean, I am using SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader(...) just to provide a concrete case. I need to wait for its callback to be triggered and then continue my process after that happens.

Comment: @codebased: I am on .NET 3.5 but that is a great idea were to be on a different version of .NET! You should definitely add a sample code as an answer as it might help someone else.

Comment: Difficult to change for you? because Async is one of easy and good feature. specially easy to understand at least.

Comment: @Denis Just look at the documentation for that method to see what you need to do to execute some code when the operation completes.  It will provide some way.

Comment: @Denis Can you show us how you're calling `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: My code is kind of complicated. But in general what would be a class that could convert an async framework with callback into a synchronous framework without a callback.

Comment: @Denis That's literally exactly what C# 5.0 did with `await`.  It *took* a new language feature to do that.  Before you have that language feature you're required to actually write the asynchronous code yourself.  Of course, `await` isn't *actually* making everything synchronous, it's just a new option for asynchronous programming that looks much closer to synchronous code than other asynchronous paradigms.

Comment: Instead of telling us what solution you've decided to use, tell us [what problem you're trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLR has a special workaround for calling WaitOne() on an STA thread.  That is **illegal**, a thread that supports apartment threading is not allowed to block.  That's very prone to cause deadlock.  The CLR will in fact start taking over the duty of pumping messages, roughly similar to [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Very roughly.

While this works to keep the *basic* plumbing of a UI thread alive, [like painting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540745/17034), this is not ever something you want to do if you can avoid it.  Quirky stuff can happen, not quite unlike using Application.DoEvents(), although the CLR code does try to minimize the damage that the re-entrancy can cause.

Big secret how they do this btw, it was intentionally omitted from the SSCLI20 distribution which is otherwise a very complete copy of the CLR code.  Chris Brumme [blogged about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/02/66219.aspx), pretty impenetrable in his usual way, but with just waving his hands and not giving away any good secrets.  The code itself is quite resistant to reverse engineering, it is *large*.  The only common signs of it is finding it back in a stack trace from a programmer that's got a very hard problem to solve.

In other words, you are invoking a code path that's highly undocumented and poorly understood.  Don't do it.  It is fundamentally unnecessary, you can always invoke back to the UI thread and continue with the code that you've now got after the WaitOne() call.  That's safe.

Comment: thank you. I tried calling WaitOne() on the STA thread and the GUI became unresponsive. Am I misreading your comment as I think you are saying this should work?

Comment: What does "unresponsive" mean?  Don't expect much out the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Seems paint event doesn't get called

Comment: I showed you an example where it *did* get called.  It doesn't matter, just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such thing that you're asking for. AFIK (as far as i know), you'll need to start a second background task or thread which waits for the AutoResetEvent to trigger in the background thread and in your UI thread, once you launch the task or 2nd thread, exit your method so it is free to do it's job of 'message pumping' as you put it.

So in this scenario, the background thread would then need to finish your processing once its AutoResetEvent is triggered to continue the processing.