# Why does Winforms UI Thread continue on seemingly unrelated work after not being able to aquire write lock using ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, deadlock

In below stack trace, there is some Winforms painting code that ends up taking a write lock using ReaderWriterLockSlim (configured with LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion). The lock is not available, so it blocks in WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne. But then, that same thread continues into NativeWindow.Callback which in turn kicks of some more painting code that wants to use that same ReaderWriterLockSlim to aquire a read lock. As there is a writer waiting, no more readers are allowed and thus the thread deadlocks.

But how is it possible that, after being stuck in WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne the first time, the thread still picks up seemingly unrelated work (NativeWindow.Callback) and continues on that? As this is a synchronous lock (thread affine lock, not async lock), it is supposed to block the thread right there, while wanting to take the write lock, no?

```
Not Flagged >   6628    0   Worker Thread   UI-thread   win32u.dll!7573249c
                    ntdll.dll!77acf29c()
                    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]
                    KERNELBASE.dll!749924c0()
                    win32u.dll!7573249c()
                    user32.dll!77906b37()
                    user32.dll!77906acd()
                    combase.dll!76fcb334()
                    combase.dll!76f8babe()
                    [Managed to Native Transition]
                    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)
                    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext)
                    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.WaitOnEvent(System.Threading.EventWaitHandle waitEvent, ref uint numWaiters, System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TimeoutTracker timeout, System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterLockType enterLockType)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TimeoutTracker timeout)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLock(System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TimeoutTracker timeout)
                    DAL.dll!DAL.PersistenceProviderBase.Read<System.__Canon>(System.Func<System.__Canon> work)
                    DAL.dll!DAL.PersistenceProviderBase.GetData(System.Type type)
                    DAL.dll!DAL.PersistenceProviderBase.GetSingleItemGeneric(System.Type type, System.Func<Model.PersistableEntity> createIfNotExists, bool linkUnit, bool linkProject)
                    Business.dll!Business.Settings.SettingsController.GetSettingsEntityGeneric(System.Type settingsType)
                    Business.dll!Business.Settings.SettingsController.GetSettingsEntity<Model.Entities.Settings.UnitWideSettings.WizardSettings>()
                    him.exe!View.Tabs.WorkflowViews.WorkflowView.GetControlsOrdered.AnonymousMethod__128_0(View.WorkflowManagerUI.WorkflowComponentControl c)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<View.WorkflowManagerUI.WorkflowComponentControl>.MoveNext()
                    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Buffer<View.WorkflowManagerUI.WorkflowComponentControl>.Buffer(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<View.WorkflowManagerUI.WorkflowComponentControl> source)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<View.WorkflowManagerUI.WorkflowComponentControl>.GetEnumerator()
                    him.exe!View.Tabs.WorkflowViews.WorkflowView.xscPaintArea_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.RaisePaintEvent(object key, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
                    DevExpress.Utils.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraScrollableControl.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintTransparentBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle, System.Drawing.Region transparentRegion)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle, System.Drawing.Color backColor, System.Drawing.Point scrollOffset)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pevent)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnPaintBackground(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, short layer)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    DevExpress.Utils.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)
                    [Native to Managed Transition]
                    user32.dll!7791d313()
                    user32.dll!778fe8da()
                    user32.dll!778fe510()
                    user32.dll!77908b69()
                    ntdll.dll!77ad0fd6()
                    win32u.dll!757327ec()
                    user32.dll!778fe340()
                    user32.dll!778fdfe0()
                    combase.dll!76fcbe1c()
                    combase.dll!76fcc0ac()
                    combase.dll!76fcb334()
                    combase.dll!76f8babe()
                    mscorlib.ni.dll!6a726b31()
                    [Managed to Native Transition]
                    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)
                    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext)
                    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.WaitOnEvent(System.Threading.EventWaitHandle waitEvent, ref uint numWaiters, System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TimeoutTracker timeout, System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterLockType enterLockType)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLockCore(System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TimeoutTracker timeout)
                    System.Core.dll!System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLock(System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TimeoutTracker timeout)
                    DAL.dll!DAL.PersistenceProviderBase.Modify<System.__Canon>(System.Func<System.__Canon> work, bool save)
                    DAL.dll!DAL.PersistenceProviderBase.ModifyNoSave<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationActuatorProperties.CommunicationActuatorProperties>>(System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationActuatorProperties.CommunicationActuatorProperties>> work)
                    DAL.dll!DAL.PersistenceProviderBase.AddDataNoSave<Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationActuatorProperties.CommunicationActuatorProperties>(Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationActuatorProperties.CommunicationActuatorProperties entity, bool linkUnit, bool linkProject)
                    Business.dll!Business.Communication.CommunicationModuleProcessor<Model.Entities.Communication.ProjectorCommunicationModule, Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationActuatorProperties.ProjectorCommunicationActuatorProperties, Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationTriggerProperties.NoCommunicationTriggerProperties>.SwapModuleForActuator(Model.Entities.Communication.CommunicationModule module, Model.Entities.WorkflowManager.Components.Actuators.CommunicationActuator actuator)
                    him.exe!View.WorkflowManagerUI.Actuators.CommunicationActuatorPropertyForm..ctor.AnonymousMethod__0(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
                    [Native to Managed Transition]
                    [Managed to Native Transition]
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.RaiseEditValueChangedCore(System.EventArgs e)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem.RaiseEditValueChanged(System.EventArgs e)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.RaiseEditValueChanged()
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.OnEditValueChanged()
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit.OnEditValueChanged()
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseAutoSearchEdit.OnEditValueChanged()
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.OnEditValueChanging(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit.OnEditValueChanging(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseEdit.EditValue.set(object value)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseEdit.AcceptPopupValue(object val)
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit.AcceptPopupValue(object val)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseEdit.UpdateEditValueOnClose(DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupCloseMode closeMode, bool acceptValue, object newValue, object oldValue)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseEdit.DoClosePopup(DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupCloseMode closeMode)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseEdit.ClosePopup(DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupCloseMode closeMode)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupBaseEdit.ClosePopup()
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemGridLookUpEditBase.DoClosePopup()
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.Handler.GridRegularRowNavigator.OnMouseUp(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo.GridHitInfo hitInfo, DevExpress.Utils.DXMouseEventArgs e)
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.Handler.GridHandler.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs ev)
                    DevExpress.Utils.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.Utils.Controls.BaseHandler.ProcessEvent(DevExpress.Utils.Controls.EventType etype, object args)
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.Handler.BaseViewHandler.ProcessEvent(DevExpress.Utils.Controls.EventType etype, object args)
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs ev)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    DevExpress.XtraEditors.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.EditorContainer.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    DevExpress.XtraGrid.v17.2.dll!DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)
                    [Native to Managed Transition]
                    user32.dll!7791d313()
                    user32.dll!778fe8da()
                    user32.dll!778fe234()
                    user32.dll!778fdfe0()
                    System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll!68c12f2c()
                    [Managed to Native Transition]
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)
                    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)
                    him.exe!View.Program.Main()
                    [Native to Managed Transition]
                    mscoreei.dll!71f6d93b()
                    mscoree.dll!71fedd65()
                    kernel32.dll!747b62c4()
                    ntdll.dll!77ac1f69()
                    ntdll.dll!77ac1f34()
```

Comment: what error? what code???

Comment: [You can't block the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540244/17034).