# How can a UI callback possibly be executed from within a Task.Result call?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, task-parallel-library

While debugging with Visual Studio 2017, I happened to take a look at the full stack trace and noticed something very strange:

*A callback from Windows Forms seems to have been executed on top of a `Task.Result` call.*

How is this possible? `Task.Result` should synchronously wait and not allow anything else to execute on it, right? Did I run into a bug or am I making a wrong assumption about something?

At first I thought it was a glitch with the stack trace, but I added some code to actually check and it does happen:

```
// Field declared in class:
[ThreadStatic]
private static bool waitingForResult;


if (waitingForResult)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("I don't even???"); // This actually throws!
waitingForResult = true;
try
{
    return task.Result;
}
finally
{
    waitingForResult = false;
}
```

The issue only seems to happen if I put a breakpoint a bit before the `.Result`. And I'm using .Net 4.7.1.

Here's the original stack trace:

```
Here we hit the surprising breakpoint (or an exception or whatever).

SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.LoadBlock(int blockIndex) Line 285 C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.GetBlock(int blockIndex) Line 228  C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.GetItem(int index) Line 212    C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.this[int].get(int index) Line 37   C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(int index) Line 328  C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.this[int].get(int index)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(int rowIndex)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.GetErrorText(int rowIndex)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle rowBounds, int rowIndex, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates rowState, bool isFirstDisplayedRow, bool isLastVisibleRow)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(System.Drawing.Graphics g, System.Drawing.Rectangle boundingRect, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipRect, bool singleHorizontalBorderAdded) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(System.Drawing.Graphics g, System.Drawing.Rectangle gridBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipRect, bool singleVerticalBorderAdded, bool singleHorizontalBorderAdded)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, short layer)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)    Unknown

Here Task.Result is called.

SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.DatabaseSchedulerBindingList<SomeNamespace.DatabaseContext, SomeNamespace.Result>.RunQuery<int>(SomeNamespace.Result lastKnownItem, bool reverse, System.Func<System.Linq.IQueryable<SomeNamespace.Result>, int> queryTransformation) Line 64 C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.RunQuery(SomeNamespace.Result lastKnownItem, bool reverse, System.Action<System.Linq.IQueryable<SomeNamespace.Result>> queryAction) Line 186   C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.LoadBlock(int blockIndex) Line 289 C#

Here the first breakpoint needs to be hit.

SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.GetBlock(int blockIndex) Line 228  C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.GetItem(int index) Line 212    C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.this[int].get(int index) Line 37   C#
SomeLibrary.dll!SomeNamespace.QueryBindingList<SomeNamespace.Result>.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(int index) Line 328  C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.this[int].get(int index)  Unknown
SomeApp.exe!SomeNamespace.ResultsView.GetImageToDisplay() Line 363  C#
SomeApp.exe!SomeNamespace.ResultsView.ResultDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 353   C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnSelectionChanged(System.EventArgs e)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.FlushSelectionChanged()  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ClearSelection() Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentCell.set(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell value) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnClearingRows() Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.ClearInternal(bool recreateNewRow)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RefreshColumnsAndRows()  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetBindings(bool metadataChanged) Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.SetList(System.Collections.IList list, bool metaDataChanged, bool applySortAndFilter)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.DataSource.set(object value)    Unknown
SomeApp.exe!SomeNamespace.ResultsView.ResultCollection.set(System.Collections.Generic.IList<SomeNamespace.Result> value) Line 130   C#
SomeApp.exe!SomeNamespace.ResultsView.RefreshResults() Line 331 C#
SomeApp.exe!SomeNamespace.ResultsView.RefreshButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 315   C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs e)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown
SomeApp.exe!SomeNamespace.Program.Main() Line 50    C#
```

Comment: That's normal, blocking an STA thread is illegal.  The CLR has a workaround for it and allows Windows messages to be dispatched anyway.  More about that in [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540244/how-is-this-possible-onpaint-processed-while-in-waitone).

Comment: As Hans notes, the Windows threading model includes a facility for dispatching certain kinds of messages under certain kinds of waiting scenarios. The Q&A he refers to answers your question exactly, as it's the same basic issue. Yet one more reason to not try to access `Result` on an uncompleted `Task` in the UI thread (frankly, re-entrancy is the least of your worries...deadlock is the much more common outcome)

Comment: @PeterDuniho The class I used can't deadlock unless used in a really abusive way (by writing blocking query expressions). It's an non-ideal solution, but it's at least a solution that doesn't hold surprises. This, however, is a whole different can of worms that goes against both the principle of least astonishment and the fail-fast principle. It breaks the most basic promise a blocking call can make: that the thread will be blocked. And it's not a widely known issue, AFAIK. Reading on concurrency in C#, I've never even seen this mentioned as a side-note.